# How to change the ajax sort params in Tabulator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabulator

How to change the ajax sort parameter in Tabulator? Currently the ajax sort params are **params.sorters[0]['field']** and **params.sorters[0]['dir']**

I cant find any solutions on how to customize it like I want to change the
**params.sorters[0]['field']** into **"orderBy"**
and
**params.sorters[0]['dir']** into **"dir"**

EDIT:
I'm using react-tabulator and Laravel as backend

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue with tabulator-tables 5.07.  In that case, it is now sending the sort params under the key `sort` instead of `sorters`.

The following example illustrates change the sorting parameter ('sort') back to the previous key ('sorters').  The following is the gist of how remote sort params can be modified:

```js
    let myTable = new Tabulator(myTableRef, {                                                                                   
      placeholder: null,                                                                                                                    
      ajaxURL: myAjaxUrl,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      ajaxConfig: {                                                                                                                         
        method: "POST",                                                                                                                     
        headers: {                                                                                                                          
          "Content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",                                                                                
        },                                                                                                                                  
      },                                                                                                                                    
      ajaxContentType: {                                                                                                                    
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },                                                                                     
        body: function(url, config, params){                                                                                                 
          // Rewrite 'sort' to 'sorters' to accomodate legacy api expectations.                                                             
          if(params.hasOwnProperty('sort')){                                                                                                
            Object.defineProperty(params, 'sorters',                                                                                        
              Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(params, 'sort'))                                                                              
            delete params['sort']                                                                                                           
          }                                                                                                                                 
          return JSON.stringify(params)                                                                                                     
        }                                                                                                                                   
      },
      // remainder of table definition.
```

Use Tabulator's `ajaxContentType` `body` to specify a function to write the body of the ajax request.  If the sort parameter is present, modify params however is required.  Finally, convert the params object to JSON and return that as the body content.

Answer (score 1):

I simplified `sort[0][field]=name&sort[0][dir]=asc` to `orderBy=name&dir=asc` by using `ajaxURLGenerator`

```
new Tabulator("#myTable", {
    autoColumns: true,
    ajaxURL: 'https://myserver.com/api/items',
    sortMode: 'remote',
    ajaxURLGenerator: function (url, config, params) {
      // Get ajaxURL
      let myUrl = url;
      
      // If sorting, then get the field name and direction
      if (params['sort'].length > 0) {
        let field = params['sort'][0]['field'];
        let dir = params['sort'][0]['dir'];
        myUrl += `&orderBy=${field}&dir=${dir}`;
      }
  
      // Return request URL
      return myUrl;
    }
  });
```

Relevant documentation:

- http://tabulator.info/docs/5.3/sort#ajax-sort
- http://tabulator.info/docs/5.3/page#remote-url

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for that is hidden away in the [Pagination](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.0/page#remote-url) documentation. I use the `paginationDataSent` option for `page` but I'm not sure if it will work the way you describe for `sorters`. You'll have to do some experimentation.

Alternately, with a little more work you can write a custom `ajaxURLGenerator` to rewrite the parameters any way you want.

Comment: Actually I already tried paginationDataSent for the sorters parameters (but still not working) as it's stated in the document
**_An array of sorters objects will then be passed in the sorters parameter of the request, the name of this parameter can be set in the paginationDataSent option, in the pagination module._**

btw thanks for your answer

Comment: This is an outdated answer, the options changed names in the 5.0 release as they were moved outside the pagination module, they are now dataSendParams  and dataReceiveParams

Comment: @OliFolkerd trying to replace the sort[0][field] & sort[0][dir] using dataSendParams but it doesn't work. Could you give a sample script on how to change it? I'm using the latest version 5.4

Comment: @OliFolkerd based on the documentation "If you need to change the names of any of these parameters to fit your existing system, you can use the dataSendParams option to set alternative parameter names". How to change sort[0][field] & sort[0][dir] using the dataSendParams?